# Paypal adaptive payment using curl

Tags: php, paypal

In my website ,i wish to implement adaptive paypal payment method. Is it  possible to implement using curl .Can any one provide php code for the adaptive payment

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to curl call for paypal

For adaptive payment first you need to generate access token with your 'clientId' and 'secret key'. Then with that access token you can call Paypal adaptive payment API.

I have given example of generating access token. and then fetching transaction details from paykey (you change your call as per your requirement).

```
//Get access token from client Id

                $ch = curl_init();
                $clientId = PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID;
                $secret = PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET;
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');// Change it to "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token" for live
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId . ":" . $secret);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                $accessToken = null;
                if (empty($result))
                    return 'Access Token could not generated';
                else {
                    $json = json_decode($result);
                    $accessToken = $json->access_token;
                }
                curl_close($ch);



                /**
                 * Get payment transaction details from
                 * - AccessToken
                 * - PayKey
                 */
                $curl = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/' . $input['payKey']);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                    'Accept: application/json',
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ));
                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $result = json_decode($response);
```

You can have reference example of paypal curl call
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-curlsamples/blob/master/execute_all_calls.php

Comment: That is really helpful! But those examples on Github are deleted. Maybe you know where can I find them again?

Answer (score 0):

you can download using this link  https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php

Comment: Can we use curl function for implementing the adaptive payment .

Answer (score 0):

```
  //This example for making a payment
```

//For Sandbox mode
$apiUrl = 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay';

//For live mode
//$apiUrl = 'https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay';

```
$_username = "**********";
$_password = "**********";
$_ipaddress = "**********";
$_application_id = "**********";
$returnUrl = "**********"
$cancelUrl = "****************";
    $receivers = array(
        array(
            'email' => "receiver1@abc.com",
            'amount' => 50,
            'primary' => true
        ),
        array(
            'email' => "receiver2@abc.com",
            'amount' => 20,
            'primary' => false
        )
    );
$requestEnvelope = array(
        'errorLanguage' => 'en_US',
        'detailLevel' => 'ReturnAll'
    );
    $packet = array(
        'actionType' => "PAY",
        'currencyCode' => "USD",
        'feesPayer' => "EACHRECEIVER",
        'receiverList' => array(
            'receiver' => $receivers
        ),
        'memo' => "Here you can write memo desc",
        'returnUrl' => $returnUrl,
        'cancelUrl' => $cancelUrl,
        'requestEnvelope' => $requestEnvelope
    );

    $headers = array(
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $_username,
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $_password,
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $_signature,
        "X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: ".$_ipaddress,
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $_application_id);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl . $call);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($packet));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    print_r( json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE));
//After execution of request , you got a paykey and using that key you can receive payment from Buyer.
```